# JavaScript cross domain Preflight Issue

Tags: javascript, cors

I am calling a local host API from Https website, each call has unique id and response is getting based on unique id.

However due to cross domain the browser generates preflight request and sends the unique request to target, that makes the actual get request duplicate.

Could you please advise on handling of this?

Tried adding headers which is not working in

Comment: The preflight request should be an `OPTIONS` request, not `GET` or `POST`. You shouldn't process the data, so the duplication shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, you mean the local host should not process the OPTIONS request sent by the browser and only process GET request?

Comment: Close. You respond to the OPTIONS request with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to let it know that the request is OK. But you don't process any of the data.

Comment: Got you, but I don't have any control over the local host API that is processing both OPTIONS and GET. Any suggestions to handle (suppress) the Options request from request side or browser settings? Please suggest

Comment: Take a look at the [CORS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to see how much control you have over it.